# Contar linha na matriz que possuam números repetidos

Tags: java, array, matriz

Queria adicionar a `linhaPreta` a quantidade de linhas somente com 0, e a `linhaBranca` somente com 1.

```
public class Pixel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] img = {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },};

        int ppreto = 0;
        int pbranco = 0;
        int linhaPreta = 0;
        int linhaBranca = 0;

        int i;
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < img[i].length; j++) {

                if (img[i][j] == 0) {
                    ppreto++;
                }

                if (img[i][j] == 1) {
                    pbranco++;
                }

                if (img[i].length == 0) {
                    linhaPreta++;
                }
                if (img[i].length == 0) {
                    linhaBranca++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.print("qtde ponto preto = " + ppreto + "\n");
        System.out.print("qtde ponto branco = " + pbranco + "\n");
        System.out.print("Qtd linha preta = " + linhaPreta + "\n");
        System.out.print("Qtd linha branca= " + linhaBranca + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Você poderia usar crase, ajuda a entender melhor... Dá uma lida na pergunta, não tem como entender se é pra ser adicionado ou adicionado a este...

Answer (score 6):

Sugestão de solução simples:

Para cada "linha" da sua imagem, some os pixels. Se soma der zero (0) a linha é "toda preta". Se a soma der igual ao número de pixels na linha, a linha é "toda branca".

```
int[][] img = {
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
    { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 
    { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },};

int linhaPreta = 0;
int linhaBranca = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {

    int soma = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < img[i].length; j++)
        soma += img[i][j];

    if(soma == 0)
        linhaPreta++;
    else if(soma == img[i].length)
        linhaBranca++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A contagem das linhas está realmente toda errada. Não faz sentido o código usado. Você tem que comparar item por item para saber se uma linha é composta toda por 0 ou toda por 1.

Desta forma criei um contador para ir acumulando o que é 0 ou 1 em cada linha individualmente. Por isto o contador zera no final de cada linha.

E só no final da linha eu posso ver se todos os elementos são do mesmo número. Obviamente isto é obtido verificando se os itens contados na linha é igual ao tamanho da linha.

```
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] img = {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },};
        int ppreto = 0;
        int pbranco = 0;
        int linhaPreta = 0;
        int linhaBranca = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            int itensPreto = 0;
            int itensBranco = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < img[i].length; j++) {
                 if (img[i][j] == 0) {
                     ppreto++;
                     itensPreto++;
                }
                if (img[i][j] == 1) {
                    pbranco++;
                    itensBranco++;
                }
            }
            if (itensPreto == img[i].length) linhaPreta++;
            if (itensBranco == img[i].length) linhaBranca++;
        }
        System.out.print("qtde ponto preto = " + ppreto + "\n");
        System.out.print("qtde ponto branco = " + pbranco + "\n");
        System.out.print("Qtd linha preta = " + linhaPreta + "\n");
        System.out.print("Qtd linha branca= " + linhaBranca + "\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KbYbQP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/incegflp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/CountRepetead.java).